# Howto get attribute from related entity in template

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I want to get the id attribute from an entity using "lazy loading".
This is my controller:

```
public function indexAction() {

    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $topics = $em->getRepository('BackendBundle:Topic')->findAll();
    $posts = $em->getRepository('BackendBundle:Post')->findAll();

    return $this->render('BackendBundle:Home:home.html.twig', 
        ['topics' => $topics, 'posts' => $posts]
    );
}
```

And here is my template block:

```
{% block article %}
    {% for post in posts %}
        <h3>
            <a href="{{ path('backend_posts_post', 
                    { 'topic_id': post.topic.id, 'post_id': post.id }) }}">
                    {{ post.title }}
            </a>
        </h3>
        <br>
        <p>{{ post.text }}</p>
        <hr>
    {% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

I'm trying to get the topic id. Every post depends on a topic and should be possible to get his identifier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. I was trying to access a post whitout topic.